# maven bundle (felix) error: missing requirement (osgi.wiring.package=io.searchbox.action)

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch-jest

I added io.searchbox dependency, even imported packet(like below) I still get error:

> Could not start bundle mvn:org.hub.app/hub/1.10.0 in feature(s)
>   hub-1.10.0: Unresolved constraint in bundle hub [176]: Unable to
>   resolve 176.0: missing requirement [176.0] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=io.searchbox.action)

I called this code fragment:

```
 HttpClientConfig clientConfig = new HttpClientConfig.Builder(
            "http://localhost:9200").multiThreaded(true).build();
 JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
 factory.setHttpClientConfig(clientConfig);
 JestClient client = factory.getObject();
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 ~ Copyright 2017 Open Networking Foundation
 ~
 ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
 ~
 ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 ~
 ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 ~ limitations under the License.
 -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.remi.app</groupId>
<artifactId>remi</artifactId>
<version>1.10.0</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<description>ONOS OSGi bundle archetype</description>
<url>http://onosproject.org</url>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <onos.version>1.11.1</onos.version>
    <onos.app.name>org.remi.app</onos.app.name>
    <onos.app.title>Remi App</onos.app.title>
    <onos.app.origin>Remi, Inc.</onos.app.origin>
    <onos.app.category>default</onos.app.category>
    <onos.app.url>http://onosproject.org</onos.app.url>
    <onos.app.readme>ONOS OSGi bundle archetype.</onos.app.readme>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <name>Sonatype Groups</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>onos-api</artifactId>
        <version>${onos.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>onlab-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>${onos.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>onos-api</artifactId>
        <version>${onos.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>*,com.sample.*</Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>com.sample.*,com.google.gson.*</Export-Package>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Embed-Dependency>groupId=io.searchbox.action</Embed-Dependency>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-scr-srcdescriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>scr</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <supportedProjectTypes>
                    <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                    <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                </supportedProjectTypes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>onos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cfg</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cfg</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>swagger</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>swagger</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>app</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>app</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the maven-bundle-plugin is by default looking for artifactId, not groupId. Please try this:

`<Embed-Dependency>jest</Embed-Dependency>`

If you want to embed all dependencies with groupId io.searchbox, you could do:

`<Embed-Dependency>groupId=io.searchbox</Embed-Dependency>`

Here is the full documentation on the [Embed-Dependency element](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#embedding-dependencies).

Comment: The io.searchbox is from the Jest (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.searchbox/jest). I tried your two solutions, both got error: (osgi.wiring.package=com.google.gson).

Comment: I am adding the gson dependency, network is slow now.